# AWS S3 PutObject aws:Referer condition doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions

I have the following bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1618374389709",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1618374385097",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::awesome-site-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "http://myawesomesite.com/",
                        "http://myawesomesite.com/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Both `s3:GetObject` and `s3:PutObject` actions work fine when I enable full public access on the bucket. But when I just enable the 1st of the 4 public access blocking settings `Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new access control lists (ACLs)`, `s3:PubObject` breaks, and I get Access Denied 403 error.

```
Error executing "PutObject" on "https://awesome-site-bucket.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/2021-04-14_011801.pdf"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `PUT https://awesome-site-bucket.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/2021-04-14_011801.pdf` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>CJBR84 (truncated...)
 AccessDenied (client): Access Denied - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>CJBR84FWEB7S9ENP</RequestId><HostId>rha67uGLTwPtyFCYE7K8z7flcSFjKxN75q2eUs6BfTPc/HI/nCCw83/13BpYN0ikqN6JLTzsrf8=</HostId></Error>
```

On the other hand, the `aws:Referer` condition seems to be working well for `s3:GetObject`. I can turn on the first 3 of the block public access options (new ACLs, any ACLs & new public bucket or access point policies), and I'm only able to retrieve an uploaded object through a link from `http://myawesomesite.com/`. Trying to access the object URL directly gives "Access Denied" in the browser, which is the correct and expected behavior.

Any ideas on what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Do you realize that aws referer is very poor protection, and basically everyone can upload anything to your bucket?

Comment: It's not obvious to me why it's poor. Only the logged in users can upload.

Comment: With little effored any one can spoof a host-header in a request. `aws:Referer` only checks for the host header

Comment: @Marcin that's a good point. However as of now, the uploading is done through an IAM user's API key, so all requests, whether GET or PUT are routed through the application server first, which is why I'm not too concerned.

Comment: When you write that `s3:PutObject` works when you enable all 4 public access options, you mean that it works for that same exact policy you have in the question?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Turning on just one of those public blocks makes the `s3:PutObject` call return access denied 403.

Comment: Interesting. How do you make `PutObject` with the referer header? Or maybe your IAM user have Iam policy with PutObject permissions which allow this as well?

Comment: Well the application is written in PHP, so I think it automatically passes the referer info in its `_$SERVER` superglobal, specifically the `"HTTP_REFERER"` key. And as mentioned, I do believe this condition is somewhat working as the GET requests are behaving correctly.

Comment: Though that's a good point you raise. I should double check the PUT request, to actually make sure all the necessary header info are present.

Comment: I know this was asked a whopping 8 years ago... but I am facing a similar issue. I am working with Laravel trying to ensure I can POST & GET from a web platform and everything is coming up 403 despite my bucket policy... If I figure it out I'll offer a solution I guess.

Comment: @Grant eventually I just worked around it by making the buckets private, and routing GET requests through the server, and enforcing access controls in app logic.